# How to format input text value to currency on angular 4 on lost focus?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

i want to format the value of the input text into currency after losing focus. How can i achieve that in angular4?

```
<input type="text" name="txtamount" [(ngModel)]="amount" />
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `CurrencyPipe` transform on `(blur)`.

```
 <input type="text" name="txtamount" [(ngModel)]="amount" 
        (blur)="transformAmount($event)" [(value)]="formattedAmount"/> 
 <br/>
 <br/>
 <div>
    Formatted Amount on loosing focus: {{ formattedAmount }}
 </div>
 <br/>
 <div>
     Formatted Amount inline with Pipe: {{ amount | currency:'USD'  }}
 </div>
```

and in your .ts code,

```
transformAmount(element: HtmlElement){
    this.formattedAmount = this.currencyPipe.transform(this.amount, 'USD');
    // Remove or comment this line if you dont want 
    // to show the formatted amount in the textbox.
    element.target.value = this.formattedAmount;
}
```

You will need to import `CurrencyPipe` from `'@angular/common'` and add that in App `providers: [ ... ]`.

---

Demo on [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s25yox)

Comment: Is is worth mentioning this will change the actual input value. This could be fine, but sometimes you only want the view value to be formatted.

Comment: yes @user3492940 , I have updated the plunker to get the value separately as well.

Comment: Great, as I remember in angularjs it was possible to have a viewValue and modelValue. This is no longer supported in angular 4 right? So you will have to use two different variables.

Comment: No you dont just use the pipe there you want to display it formatted and let the variable like its is.`{{amount | currency:'USD':false}}`, this way it will not change the variable itself

Comment: @Doomenik he wanted that on loosing focus, that's why I provided a solution with `(blur)`. Updated my answer with inline transformation of `amount` variable.

Comment: @Faisal I just answered user3492940 question, your solution was totally fine.

Comment: This is exactly what i want. Thanks guys.

Comment: @Faisal though you don't mention any symbol to display as `{{ amount | currency:'USD' : true  }}` still it showing currency symbol and by default it showing 2 decimal points `.00` . how come this happens.

Comment: if you dont mention that then it uses the default

Comment: I don't need any decimal numbers then how could I over come this. see this http://plnkr.co/edit/xnN1HnJtTel6WA24GttR?p=preview working properly but what is the difference?

Comment: @k11k2 you can use the following: `{{31.004 | currency:'USD':true:'1.0-0'}}`

Comment: Your transformAmount function I think has a type error: it should be receiving an 'event: FocusEvent', not an HtmlElement, since you are passing $event from the template. Events have the .target property, not elements... To be even clearer, in my code I cast event.type into an HTMLInputElement, and then set the .value on that, to avoid any type errors.

Comment: Couldn't you just have one-way binding on your NgModel and have the pipe in that?

`<input type="text" name="txtamount" [ngModel]="amount | currency:'USD'"(blur)="transformAmount($event)"/>`

Comment: Plunker no longer appears functional

Comment: @CaptainPrinny , thanks for pointing that out. I have added the updated stackblitz demo.